# VSCode debugger with webpack and node js - breakpoints grey -> "breakpoints set but not yet bound"

Tags: node.js, debugging, webpack, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

New here. I am trying to configure vscode debugger for my node.js web app. Used tech is node.js, webpack, pug and plain old js. I have followed several guides and steps to try and configure this and admittedly lack of understanding of different parts is key issue here.

Aim: start localhost with webpack and have breakpoints in server files and front end files that will help to debug or at very least tell me what variables are being transferred at any given time.

Issue: constantly getting message "breakpoints set but not yet bound".

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Below pasted files that I am using to run this and console output --> Configurations used (this is basically one of the latest examples I have tried):

---

[launch.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daUJi.png)

[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sn8o1.png)

[webpack.config.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSegD.png)

[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQc1p.png)

followed by server started

Comment: There are at least a dozen different reasons why this could be happening. If you could put up a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), we'd probably be a lot better able to help you figure it out.